# How can i change the order of nodes in a list

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am reading API input from a csv and below is the list i am getting

```
[{'name': 'john', 'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}]}]
```

in above list, i want to change the order i.e

```
[{'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}],'name': 'john'}]
```

can anyone help here, thanks in advance

Comment: `[{k: l[0][k]for k in list(l[0].keys())[::-1]}]` where `l` is tour original list. But it does not make sense to have a order in `dict` in terms of index, you are anyway use keys, but python 3.7 onwardswill allow though

Comment: Dictionaries are not sortable. Why you want to sort it? what is the main problem?

Comment: The main problem is: I am reading some data from a CSV sheet below is my code

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do there is *not* change a list order, it's changing a *dictionary* order:

```py
Trying to swap these two, elements of a dictionary.
     |                |
[{'name': 'john', 'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}]}]
||                             ||__________dictionary__________||||
||                             |______________list______________|||
||___________________________dictionary__________________________||
|_______________________________list______________________________|
```

Dictionaries do not *have* intrinsic order, the order can change arbitrarily when you add or remove keys (and possibly at *any* time).

If you want to *display* them in a specific order, you'll need to do that explicitly, possibly with a monstrosity like:

```py
mylist = [{'name': 'john', 'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}]}]

print(mylist)
print("\n".join([f"[{{'loan_info': {x['loan_info']}, 'name': '{x['name']}'" for x in mylist]), end="}]\n")
```

which gives you:

```py
[{'name': 'john', 'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}]}]
[{'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}], 'name': 'john'}]
```

But, given how monstrous that code actually *is* (and how much effort will be required to add fields without blowing up your skull), you may want to opt for a better pretty printing solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
I need to add the dict loan_info at the beginning of the list as I need to pass that in a post request to forming that API payload below is the code 
The main problem is: I am reading some data from a CSV sheet below is my coded

f = pd.read_csv('/testdata.csv',
 dtype={
        "amount": str,
        "rate": float,
        "debt_type": str,
        "country": str
                   })
finalList = []
finalDict = {}
grouped = df.groupby(['name'])
for key, value in grouped:
    dictionary = {}
    j = grouped.get_group(key).reset_index(drop=True)
    dictionary['name'] = j.at[0, 'name']
    dictList = []
    anotherDict = {}
    for i in j.index:
        anotherDict['amount'] = j.at[i, 'amount']
        anotherDict['rate'] = j.at[i, 'rate']
        dictList.append(anotherDict)
        print(dictList)
        dictionary['loan_info'] = dictList        
        finalList.append(dictionary)
        json.dumps(finalList)
        
now the list order I want to achieve is below:
[{'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}],'name': 'john'}]

and the current order is
[{'name': 'john', 'loan_info': [{'amount': '9000', 'rate': 12.2}]}]
```

Comment: Usually, the order of keys in dict doesn't matter if you are just gonna pass the data to the API. Instead of using normal dict use `OrderedDict`